# How many ways are there to get a sum of $25$ when $10$ distinct dice are rolled?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have come across the following problem and have given it a good attempt below. I am wondering if I have proceeded correctly, and if not if someone could show me the correct answer or maybe a more efficient solution, thanks!

> How many ways are there to get a sum of $25$ when $10$ distinct dice are rolled?

Each die can be a number from $1$ to $6$. With $10$ dice, our generating function becomes:

$$g(x) = (x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^{10}$$

We want to find the coefficient of $x^{25}$. Observe that the expression inside the brackets is a finite geometric series with $a=x, r=x, n=6$. Thus we have

$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^{10}$$
$$=\left(\frac{x(1-x^6)}{(1-x)}\right)^{10}$$
$$=x^{10}(1-x^6)^{10}(1-x)^{-10}$$

Then,

$$(1-x^6)^{10}(1-x)^{-10}$$
$$=\sum \binom{10}{i}(-x^6)^i \cdot\sum\binom{-10}{j}(-x)^j$$

In order to get terms that involve $x^{15}$ there are $3$ combinations of $i$ and $j$ to consider so that $6i+j = 15$

Thus we have:

$$\left[ \binom{10}{0}(-1)^0\binom{-10}{15}(-1)^{15}\right] + \left[ \binom{10}{1}(-1)^1 \binom{-10}{9}(-1)^9\right] + \left[\binom{10}{2}(-1)^2\binom{-10}{3}(-1)^3\right]$$
$$ = \left[\binom{10}{0}\binom{-10}{15}(-1)\right]+\left[ \binom{10}{1} \binom{-10}{9} \right] + \left[ \binom{10}{2} \binom{-10}{3}(-1)\right] $$

$$=\left[ \binom{10}{0}\binom{10+15-1}{15}(-1)^{15}(-1)\right] + \left[ \binom{10}{1} \binom{10+9-1}{9}(-1)^9\right] + \left[ \binom{10}{2}\binom{10+3-1}{3}(-1)^3(-1)\right]$$

$$= \left[ \binom{10}{0}\binom{24}{15}\right] - \left[ \binom{10}{1}\binom{18}{9}\right] + \left[ \binom{10}{2}\binom{12}{3}\right]$$

$$= 831204$$

Comment: 831204 is correct.

Comment: @awkward are my workings and logic correct?

Comment: @gimusi does this solution look correct?

Comment: I haven't checked all the details (which are probably correct, since you got the right final answer), but yes, your method is correct.  I cheated and used a computer algebra system to check your final answer.

Comment: @awkward yeah it was a lot of algebra

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet so adding here: I haven't checked the math, but just for fun https://ideone.com/IKt8OR

Comment: is that a code for this problem?

Comment: Yes but a very very crude code. It _MIGHT_ be possible to make this more efficient but I just typed it out for fun.

Comment: well I appreciate you typing it up, at least it confirms the number I got for my answer

Answer (score 1):

You will enjoy reading about Polynomial Coefficients [here](http://community.dur.ac.uk/c.c.d.s.caiado/multinomial.pdf).  See specifically Theorem 2.1 in the referenced paper on the sum of discrete uniform random variables.

What you are looking for is what's referred to as multinomials.  Your approach tries to distill a multinomial into its basic binomial counter parts.  There is a recursive relationship between multinomials, as discussed in the referenced paper.

Comment: is my answer correct?

Comment: I don't think so, since what you mentioned earlier in your post is $x^{25}$ and what you actually show is for $x^{15}$.  I think your methodology is fine, but lengthy.